How to make a bookmarklet that calls script from a link usable offline?
So, I recently stumbled across Eruda, a mobile bookmarklet that lets mobile users basically have dev console in any site. I wanted to make this useable offline but that’s proving harder than I thought. It calls on a link, https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda, and if a copy the code from that and replace the call function with it it doesn’t work. Some help? I wanna use this offline. Also, is it possible to just get the javascript console out of it to sue as a separate bookmarklet?
Here is the code
javascript:
(function%20()%20%7B%20var%20script%20=%20document.createElement('script');%20script.src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda%22;%20document.body.append(script);%20script.onload%20=%20function%20()%20%7B%20eruda.init();%20%7D%20%7D)();


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
